# ¿Cómo crear ItemTemplate para ListView WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Como puedo crear **vistas** como las que tiene **Windows** (Iconos grandes, Lista, detalles, etc) para una **ListView en C# WPF** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes guardar los distintos estilos como Recursos en Diccionarios de Recursos (imagino que eso lo sabes), y luego los vas asignando mediante el codebehind

```
// Agregar el atributo de clase donde manejarás el listview
private ResourceDictionary _myResourceDictionary;
public ResourceDictionary MyResourceDictionary
{
    get { return _myResourceDictionary; }
    set { _myResourceDictionary = value; }
}

// Crear un método para cargar el diccionario o cargarlo directo en el constructor, 
//yo creo un método
private void LoadResourceDictionary()
{
    MyResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
    MyResourceDictionary.Source = new 
    System.Uri("pack://application:,,,/Dictionaries/MyListViewStyles.xaml", 
    System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}

// Entonces ahora agrego el método al constrcutor

ctor()
{
    LoadResourceDictionary();
}

// Ahora cuando quiera setear un estilo lo hago así
private void AplicarEstilo()
{
    Style miEstilo = (Style)MyResourceDictionary["ListViewBigIconsStyle"];
    miListBox.Style = miEstilo;
}
```

Comment: y sabes como puedo crear estos estilos para crear las diferentes vistas, porque he visto ejemplos pero no me funcionan bien

Comment: Mira, haz una vista en una ventana común, déjala tal como te gustaría que se viera y luego tomas el grid de esa ventana y lo pones en el DataTemplate del ListView, obviamente añadiendo los ajustes necesarios, por ejemplo agregando el HorizontalContentAlignment en el ListView que debe quedar en Stretch para que el Grid del DataTemplate quede usando todo el ancho..  La verdad esto da para otra pregunta, ya que requiere agregar ejemplos de codigo.